# Proper way to store shared class variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A somewhat simple question, but I'd like some help understanding exactly how classes work in Python. Specifically, when are class variables set, and are they overwritten every time an instance of that class is created?

Here is the general situation. I have a table of data that I would like all instances of a certain class to be able to access. The problem is that this table sits on a database server. I want to connect to the database automatically and retrieve this table into memory the first time a instance of this class is created, but not any time after that.

It seems like a class variable would work, but I just wanted to verify that this would be the case. My program is going to be creating hundreds of instances of this class so I definitely don't want to be accidentally making hundreds of database calls for the same table or storing hundreds of copies of the same table in memory.

Would I be able to write something like the following? Assume that "get_table_from_db" is a function that connects to a database and returns a pandas dataframe with the relevant table.

```
class ExampleClass:
    table1 = get_table_from_db(arguments)
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.value = self.table1.iloc[x, y]

obj1 = ExampleClass(0, 0)
obj2 = ExampleClass(0, 1)
```

Basically, when I run this script, I want to run "get_table_from_db" once, either before or when obj1 is created and store the relevant dataframe to table1. When obj2 is created, I do not want to call "get_table_from_db" again because table1 already exists. However, I still want it to have access to table1 for some of its methods because it will need that data available to it (as an example, I assigned self.value equal to a specific cell in the table, but my actual code is going to be more complicated than that).

Also, a similar question. If the above method works, can I then reset a class variable from within the class? For example, will something like the following allow me to modify (and by modify I mean redownload) the class variable for all instances of the class?

```
class ExampleClass:
    table1 = get_table_from_db(arguments)
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.value = self.table1.iloc[x, y]
    def reset_table(self):
        ExampleClass.table1 = get_table_from_db(arguments)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class variable will be initialized once, when the class is declared (so before either `obj1` or `obj2` are created), so your code will work the way you think.

With regards to your second question, you should do it like this:

```
class ExampleClass:
    @classmethod
    def reset_table(cls):
        cls.table1 = get_table_from_db(arguments)
```

That way you can call either `obj.reset_table()` or `ExampleClass.reset_table()` without needing an instance of `ExampleClass`.